# JavaScript function works in JsFiddle but not in ASP.NET Partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an event that I want to fire on keyup of an input. the code works perfectly fine in JsFiddle, but when I run in ASP.NET MVC Partial view, nothing happens.

So for example this is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wp8hb6a/)

Exactly the same code (except the part with click me, to add text field) does not work in my view. What is even stranger that this code:

```
$(document).on("keyup","#propName", function () {
   alert($("#propName").val());
});
```

works without any problems and the event is fired, but as soon as I add an `IF` statement the code is not executing at all (also no error messages in the console)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You fiddler works with the if statement

Comment: yes I know and that's what's bugging me... in my .net view as soon as I add the IF statement everything just stops

Comment: Check the console for errors

Comment: no error in the console and also if I try to put a debugger; its not reached

Comment: What line of code is causing the problem?

Comment: Thats what I am trying to find out.. as soon as I add an IF statement everything just stops

Comment: Is the script directly embedded in the view? If so, view source of the page, it might be getting output differently than you expected due to nesting.

Comment: add all js codes to parent view